# Improper integral $\int_0^3 (1-x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})) dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have to determine the convergence of 
$\int_0^3 (1-x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})) dx$

Can I say that

$(1-x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}}))\leq1+x^2$

and since $\int_0^3 1+x^2 dx$ 
is not even improper, the integral 
$\int_0^3 (1-x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})) dx$ is convergent?

Comment: So if $x$ goes to $0$, what can you say about the limit $x^2sin(1/x^2)$ ?

Comment: Its value is $1$, but is this enough to determine the convergence of the integral?

Comment: we have $$1/3\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }-2/3\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }{\it FresnelS}
 \left( 1/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {\pi }}} \right) -9\,\sin
 \left( 1/9 \right) -2\,\cos \left( 1/9 \right) +3
$$ as the searched result

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso No, but it is a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^3 \left(1-x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\ dx$$
$$=\int_0^3\ dx-\int_0^3 x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx$$
$$=3-\int_0^3 x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx$$
Since
$$\int_0^3 x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx \leq \int_0^3 x^2\ dx$$
And
$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\int_t^3 x^2\ dx=\frac13\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+} \left(3^3-t^3\right)=9$$
Therefore by the integral comparison test,
$$\int_0^3 x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx=\mbox{convergent}$$
Which implies that
$$\int_0^3 \left(1-x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\ dx=\mbox{convergent}$$